# mysql select while skipping some number of rows

Tags: mysql

Is there a mysql syntax that can hop some rows?

For example

```
id          value
1             a 
2             b
3             c
4             d
5             e
6             f
7             g
8             h
9             i
```

SELECT * FROM table HOP BY 2

so the result will be

```
id          value
3             c
6             f
9             i
```

or

```
id          value
1             a 
4             d
7             g
```

Take note: We don't know the actual ID of a row so we can't use a WHERE clause like this

```
WHERE ID is a multiple of 3 or etc.
```

Comment: I don't think there is an sql method to do this, though I could give a simple php answer, or a not-so simple php answer.

Comment: Can you give me some alternative @JamesG.

Comment: If you don't want to use where clause than try using HAVING CLAUSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize you could do math in sql queries. Learned something new. Cool. Here's code that would select 1, 4, and 7.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (ID+2)%3 = 0 AND ID>1");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

I don't see why it wouldn't work if id has gaps, as the man with ?mandarin? symbols for a name said.

Modulus(%), if you don't know, gives the number of decimals given by a division problem. So 3/3=1, with no decimals, so 3%3=0, whereas 4/3=1.333333..., so 4/3 equals infinity(not really in programming, but close enough).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM hoptable WHERE ID%3 =0 AND ID>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @row_idx := 0;
SELECT *, (@row_idx := @row_idx + 1) AS idx
FROM table
HAVING idx % 3 = 0;
```

You probably want to include an ORDER BY clause so the row index can actually be meaningful though. You can't rely on the result being ordered by id without specifying it.